# getElementsByName() not working?

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter, getelementsbyname

I have a Javascript function which should update a hidden input field in my form with a number that increments every time the function is called.

It worked originally with **getElementById()** however because I had to redesign my form I cannot use the php function to assign an individual ID to the element so all I have is a unique name for that element.

So instead I decided to use **getElementsByName()** from Javascript to modify the element.

Here is the HTML of that element

```
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="staff_counter">
```

This is my Javascript code:

```
window.onload=function()
{

//function is activated by a form button 

var staffbox = document.getElementsByName('staff_counter');
                    staffbox.value = s;


                s++;
}
```

I am getting no errors on Firebug when the function is called and the input field is not getting a value given to it.

It was working with getElementById() but why all of a sudden it does not work with getElementsByName()?

- -I have checked that it is the only unique element in the document.
- -I checked for any errors on Firebug when activating the function

Here is the code I use from Codeigniter to make the element

```
// staff_counter is name and the set_value function sets the value from what is
//posted so if the validation fails and the page is reloaded the form element does
// not lose its value

echo form_hidden('staff_counter', set_value('staff_counter'));
```

Thanks

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/43795346/5289704

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`document.getElementsByName()` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Why_is_NodeList_not_an_Array.3F), so you have to access it by an index: `document.getElementsByName('staff_counter')[0]` (depending on how many of these you have).

You also have access to a `length` property to check how many Elements were matched.

Comment: It's **not** an array. It's a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Why_is_NodeList_not_an_Array.3F). Big difference.

Answer (score 4):

Just had a similar issue, I resolved it with a simple loop over the array. The code below will go through and disable all the buttons with the name of 'btnSubmit'.

```
for (var i=0;i<document.getElementsByName('btnSubmit').length;i++){
    document.getElementsByName('btnSubmit')[i].disabled=true;
}
```

Comment: move getElements... out of the cycle

    var _elements = document.getElementsByName('btnSubmit');
    for (var i=0;i<_elements.length;i++){
        _elements[i].disabled=true;
    }