# Firefox doesn't post form Element Values

Tags: javascript, forms, firefox, coldfusion, submit

I have a very simple form (.cfm page).  I'm submitting the form via AJAX in my javascript file.  The form works fine in IE, Safari and Chrome, but doesn't work in FF (v18.0).

Here is my form:

```
<form name="LoginForm">
<input class="newstext" type="text" name="userLogin" id="userLogin">
<input class="newstext" type="password" name="passLogin" id="passLogin">
<input type="button" name="login" value=" Login " onClick="validateLogin();">
</form>
```

Javascript code:

```
function validateLogin() {

    if (document.getElementById('userLogin').value == '') {
    alert('Please enter your username');
    document.getElementById('userLogin').style.backgroundColor='yellow';
    document.getElementById('userLogin').focus();
    return false;
} 

if (document.getElementById('passLogin').value == '') {
    alert('Please enter your password');
    document.getElementById('passLogin').style.backgroundColor='yellow';
    document.getElementById('passLogin').focus();
    return false;
} 

ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm("LoginForm", "loginForm_action.cfm", submitLoginCallback, submitLoginerrorHandler);
return true;
```

}

When I try to login in, the form element values aren't being passed. So when it hits the cfc, the cfc says "Element USERLOGIN is undefined in FORM. 
The error occurred on line 9."   Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the code for your loginForm_action.cfm? Do you get the two alert()s in FF and then an error?

Comment: The two alerts say undefined for both. The action page has a cfinvoke to my cfc that validates the form against the DB (<cfinvoke method="validateLogin" component="_cfc/login" returnvariable="userID"></cfinvoke>). When it gets to that point I get the following error message: Element USERLOGIN is undefined in FORM. <br>The error occurred on line 9.

Comment: Now that you've updated your code, would you update your question please.  You're question is "any ideas why name and pass are undefined" as it stands, name and pass are not in the code. define `still not working in firefox` copy paste the exact error, is it a JS or CF error? Help us to help you, my friend.

Comment: This question really needs the javascript tag as well but I think we should spare that community until we get a `good` question out of the OP.

Comment: @Travis Thanks, I have updated the question and copied the error that is being returned from CF.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried doing a cfdump in your cfc of the form scope to see what you do get?

Comment: try <form name="LoginForm" id = "LoginForm"> (I'm curious to see if the function is picking up the form's name in firefox) Docs say ID or Name of the form but I'd like to eliminate this as a possibility.

Comment: how are you passing the arguments to your cfc? the <cfinvoke> code you posted in your comment does not seem to pass any form values to the cfc - you need to pass them explicitly either as <cfinvokeargument>s, or as named attribute=value pairs in <cfinvoke> tag, or as argumentCollection structure.

Comment: the cfc probably directly accesses the form scope, they don't need to be passed in.

Comment: is this actually a `cfform` or are you using the `cfajaximport` tag somewhere?

Comment: @azawaza `A CFC shares the Form, URL, Request, CGI, Cookie, Client, Session, Application, Server, and Flash scopes with the calling page. Variables in these scopes are also available to all pages that are included by a CFC. These variables do not have any behavior that is specific to CFCs.` from: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7dfb.html

Comment: @Travis Right you are. Have not used <cfinvoke> in ages and forgot that!

Answer (score 1):

When you posted the question did StackOverflow invite you to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967297/getelementsbyname-not-working)?

**Edit starts here**

If you were not invited to look, you weren't.

The answer that got 6 votes was, "`document.getElementsByName()` returns an array, so you have to access it by an index: `document.getElementsByName('staff_counter')[0]` (depending on how many of these you have).

You also have access to a `length` property to check how many Elements were matched."

It makes sense to me given that you were presented with undefined variable problems.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to include the salient point(s)? Links can break, even on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk I was kind of wondering the same thing. If you search for `document.getElementsByName` not working in Firefox you get lots of results.

Comment: So you're suggesting that I use getElementsbyName instead of ID? Is that correct?

Comment: Read the first line of the accepted answer: _"document.getElementsByName() returns an array, so you have to access it by an index"_

Comment: +1 what @PeterBoughton said. I'm guessing that IE and Chrome are defaulting for you but FF is not.

Comment: The reason I phrased the answer the way I did is that whenever I post a question, I get lot's of invitations to look at other threads to make sure the question is not a duplicate.

Comment: The other point to note is why not just use `getElementById`, since you've gone to the trouble of defining ids for the fields?

Comment: @ Juffy I actually thought I had posted my code with getElementsbyId. It appears I made a mistake when I posted and just went with it to try and make it work.

Comment: in Dan's defense, this answer was very valid to the originally asked question.  I hope nobody else goes on a down-vote-marathon...

Comment: Yes it was I apologize for teh confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys here is what I did to fix this issue.

It seems when the form was processed by Firefox there was malformed HTML caused by my `<form>` tag being inside a `<table>` tag and the cooresponding end tag (`</form>`) was also within the `<table>` tag.  After moving the form tags around the table the form work as expected.

Thank you all for trying to help me solve this issue that was difficult to figure out and I apologize for the confusion within my initial question.

David

Comment: That's why posting your code and not a "represented rewrite" is much more helpful.